# C# CefSharp Blank Page

Tags: c#, browser, cefsharp

I am trying to learn how to use CefSharp as a browser in c# (unless anyone can suggest any better alternatives).

Initially I set the configuration to Any CPU (and edited the .csproj and app.config) , but the browser didn't display any content, instead it just shows a white/grey screen.

I then tried changing the configuration to x64 (as my PC is x64), but after doing got the following errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Winforms' does not exist in the 
namespace 'CefSharp'

The type or namespace name 'ChromiumWebBrowser' could not be found

The "FindUnderPath" task was not given a value for the required parameter 
"Path". 

The OutputPath property is not set for project 'cef.csproj'.  Please check 
to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration 
and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x64'.  This 
error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-
to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is 
not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build 
using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform.
```

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            string url = "https://www.google.co.uk/";
            chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
            this.pContent.Controls.Add(chrome);
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }




        private void pContent_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you have to use x86 for CefSharp.

Comment: You can use AnyCPU, x86 or x64 see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for a working example. The https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/demo/anycpu branch uses AnyCPU.

Comment: Have you found the answer? I'm following this tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOzBVy-sDbM and I have exactly the same issue as yours.

Comment: yes, @RonBeyer was right... on the config manager we should switch it into x86 and everything went smoothly.